# Android lifecyle question re: incrementing a counter

Tags: android, lifecycle

My android application tracks the number of correct answers while the user is in process of taking a quiz. If the user's answer matches the correct answer, a counter to track this is incremented. This logic takes place in the "onResume" method.

The problem is, if the user presses the home button from this activity, then re-enters the application, it resumes at this activity, and the counter gets incremented again.

The only solution I can think of is to set the correct answer field to a "magic number" such as 99 when a correct answer happens, and check for that first before going into the answer-checking logic. If it's 99, then skip the answer-checking logic and just redisplay.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the real problem you have and in specific why you're incrementing a counter of correct answers in the `onResume` event. You have for sure some kind of button where the user confirms his answer. Don't you verify the correctness of the given answer there, i.e. in the button's click method?
Implementing such logic in the `onResume`event is somehow dangerous, because it is called by the underlying Android OS.

Comment: Both answers were good, so I just picked one and upvoted both. The reason the answer isn't checked in the onClick event is that it passes control to another activity, which displays the correct answer, a running total of correct answers, remaining questions, etc.  What I hadn't been getting is that when that activity finishes, it goes off the stack and is destroyed - so the onCreate is called every time.

Comment: Hmm..I don't know your app's logic in detail, but an activity should normally be used for a single use case, i.e. to display a list of items. From the Android developer site: "...is a single, focused thing that the user can do". Basically the proposing of the question as well as the displaying of the correct answer/if the answer was correct is in my opinion the focus of a single activity. You can do that by hiding/showing elements on that activity. The kind of question that is being displayed is given by the intent uri passed to the activity itself. In this way you'd solve your issue :)

Comment: It had occurred to me to use the same screen for both the question an answer. One problem is, it makes the layout a bit more crowded/complicated, due extra fields and to managing which fields to display/hide. Although I *might* go that way if I were to do it again, still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using an application lifecycle method to cause a non-lifecycle effect.  Please post some code.  If you are relying on onResume to indicate that you have returned from a different Activity, you should take a look at startActivityForResult.  If this isn't the case, you'll need to post some more description of your program.  You shouldn't, however, be using onResume for anything besides setting up your applications state, since you can't always control how its called.